# link txt file to excel in both directions

Tags: excel, txt

1.) I have txt file (value.txt) with just one numerical value. Only one number in only one line.

2.) That numerical value nead to be inserted in excel table in cell A1

3.) Then excel do some calculus and put result in cell A2 (numerical value)

4.) Question is how to write value from A2 back to txt file (value.txt) to replace current value writen in it?

best regards!

Comment: Using VBA, you can create a macro which reads that textfile and does all those things you're looking for. Plenty of examples here on the site and all over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dominique, you will need a macro.  The following code should give you a good start:

```
Sub mRecalculateValue()
    
    'Declares variables
    Dim lOrigVal, lNewVal As Long
    '
    'Opens .txt file (Change path to where you have saved your file)
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\stuar\Value.txt", Origin:=437, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
        , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
    'Stores existing value from the text file, assumin no headers, if there are headers change range from A1 to B1
    lOrigVal = Range("A1").Value
    
    'Applies the formula to the existing value
    lNewVal = lOrigVal + 3
    
    'Stores the New file back in the .txt file
    ActiveCell.Value = lNewVal
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
End Sub
```